# Javascript response on same page

Tags: javascript, html, date

```js
function check(){
    var d = new Date(); 
    var date = d.getDate(); 
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1; 
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var state = document.form1.state.value;
        
    if(state==1){
        document.getElementById("expDate").innerHTML = (date + 4) + "/" + month + "/" + year; 
    }
    else if(state==2){
        document.getElementById("expDate").innerHTML = (date + 7) + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" >
 <table width="20%">
  <tr>
   <td>Select State: </td>
   <td>
    <select name="state">
     <option value=1>CANSAS</option>
     <option value=2>NEW YORK</option>
    </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Expected Delivered:</td>
   <td><p id="expDate"></p>
   </td>
  </tr>
   <td>
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onClick="return check()">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

I'm creating a postage calculator using HTML and JavaScript. The calculator will calculate the expected delivery date when users select the state option and submit. After the submit, the selected value will be caught by JavaScript and used as to recognize which area of the state is (south, west, else). Eg: cansas, which is west, duration will be 5 days. Then in the same page the expected delivery date will be shown after it calculate by adding the 5 with current date.

Comment: Nice. But where is your code?

Comment: Please make a [mcve]

Comment: Here are the script that left behind in javascript: var d = new Date();
 var date = d.getDate();
 var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
 var year = d.getFullYear()
 document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date + "/" + month + "/" + year;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Your code actually sets the innerHTML for 'extDate' as well but after that it submits the form and value disappears as form resets.
Only thing that you have to do is to **prevent** the form to be submitted by returning **false**.

```
function check(e) {
            // e.preventDefault();
            var d = new Date(); 
            var date = d.getDate(); 
            var month = d.getMonth() + 1; 
            var year = d.getFullYear();

            // document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            var state = document.form1.state.value;

            if (state == 1) {
                document.getElementById("expDate").innerHTML = (date + 4) + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            }
            else if (state == 2) {
                document.getElementById("expDate").innerHTML = (date + 7) + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I have checked the following the code and for 'New York', it returns Expected Delivered:
26/10/2018